# How to remove unused keys in Flutter Intl

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

In my flutter app I am using [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_utils) by its [official Jetbrains plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13666-flutter-intl) to handle the localizations, and it works great. Currently i'm supporting 3 different languages, therefore I have 3 different locale.

For example, if I add a `key` only for my default language, the tool creates the `key` in the `intl_en.arb` and the boilerplate in the `I10n.dart` and `messages_en.dart`. Later i can add the same `key` in the `intl_it.dart` and the tool updates the boilerplate where is needed.

But i can't find how to safely remove a key, o remove all the unused keys.
Am i missing some documentation?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe not.
According to the [opened issue](https://github.com/localizely/flutter-intl-intellij/issues/13), that feature should be available in one of the upcoming plugin releases.

Comment: You are right. I've also asked directly to Intl and yet i have not received an answer https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/279

Answer (score 3):

I have written a package to address this use case. You can use it to either just list the unused keys or remove them altogether.

https://pub.dev/packages/translations_cleaner

Comment: Thank you for having taken the time to publish this package, it has helped me!

Comment: Didn't work for me. I've filed an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted my simple solution originally mentioned [here](https://github.com/localizely/flutter-intl-intellij/issues/13#issuecomment-1204931707) to GitHub in [this unused_l10n reposiotory](https://github.com/orestesgaolin/unused_l10n)

You can use it by cloning locally and then calling:

```bash
dart run bin/unused_l10n.dart -p /Users/path/to/the/project
```